# Blender imported video distorted

Tags: movie-clip-editor

I took a video using my Sony A7iii with the AVCHD file format. I put it in Premiere Pro to trim it and I exported it as H.264 to an mp4 file. The exported video looks fine with Microsoft's Movies and TV App, but once I have imported it into Blender, the footage became distorted. Which software caused the problem and how do I fix it?[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to de-interlace the video when you export it.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much.